# connected multiselect filters in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I would like to connect the selection options for streamlit multiselect.

Lets assume I have the following dataframe

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| A | red |
| A | blue |
| B | black |
| B | blue |
| C | green |
| C | black |
| C | blue |
| D | green |
| D | yellow |
| D | white |

and two multiselect filters (one for each unique values of each column)

I would like the following:

- When the end user selects an option (or options) for the 'Name' column, the options for the other multiselect for the 'Color' should be updated accordingly and vice versa.

This is my unsuccessful attempt so far.

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({

    'Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
    'Color':['red', 'blue', 'blue', 'black', 'black', 'green', 'blue', 
    'yellow', 'white', 'green', 'purple']
})

tmp = df.copy()

st.title("Connected filters examples")


st.markdown('<br>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

if 'color_class' in st.session_state:
    if st.session_state.color_class:
        tmp = tmp[tmp['Color'].isin(st.session_state.color_class)]
    else:
        tmp = df.copy()

name = st.multiselect(
    'Choose Name',
    tmp['Name'].unique(),
    [], key='name_class')

if 'name_class' in st.session_state:
    if st.session_state.name_class:
        tmp = tmp[tmp['Name'].isin(st.session_state.name_class)]
    else:
        tmp = df.copy()

color = st.multiselect(
    'Choose Color',
    tmp['Color'].unique(),
    [], key='color_class')

st.dataframe(tmp)
```

for example if the end users selects the color 'red' and 'green' the options for name should be 'A' 'C' and 'D'

Comment: If you use the code i have you can the issue by doing the following.  firstly choose color Blue, then select Name A. I would like it to update the Color selection with only red and blue.

Comment: It seems to me like the values under column "Name" are the priorities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution - all described in the inline comments

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

# Create a dictionary of data
data = {'Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
       'Color': ['red', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'white']}

# Create a DataFrame from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create an empty DataFrame to store filtered data
df_filtered = pd.DataFrame()

# Initialize the name_select variable
name_select = None

# Get a list of unique color options from the original DataFrame
color_options = df['Color'].unique()

# Create a multi-select widget to select colors
color_select = st.multiselect("Select Color", color_options, key="color")

# Create a flag to track if the color select has been changed
color_select_changed = False

# If the user selects one or more colors:
if color_select:
    # Set the flag to indicate the color select has been changed
    color_select_changed = True
    
    # Filter the original DataFrame to only include rows with the selected colors
    df_filtered = df[df['Color'].isin(color_select)]
    
    # Get a list of unique name options from the filtered DataFrame
    name_options = df_filtered['Name'].unique()
    
    # Create a multi-select widget to select names
    name_select = st.multiselect("Select Name", name_options, key="name")

# If the user selects one or more names, but the color select has not been changed:
if name_select and not color_select_changed:
    # Filter the original DataFrame to only include rows with the selected names
    df_filtered = df[df['Name'].isin(name_select)]
    
    # Get a list of unique color options from the filtered DataFrame
    color_options = df_filtered['Color'].unique()
    
    # Create a multi-select widget to select colors
    color_select = st.multiselect("Select Color", color_options, key="color")

# If the filtered DataFrame is not empty, display it
if not df_filtered.empty:
    st.write(df_filtered)
```

If the end users selects the color 'red' and 'green' the options for name shows up as 'A' 'C' and 'D'.

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thank for this, but it is not working properly. For example, if you select blue, and then in the multiselect below you select A it does not filter the table. It will still show A, B, C.

Answer (score 0):

add the below line after name_select multifilter for the dataframe to include only selected names

```
df_filtered = df[df['Name'].isin(name_select)]
```